# c# console app simple calculator not working

Tags: c#, console-application, calculator

i was trying to make a calculater with a function but when i want to return my value 'calculation' , it will give the value of the variable in my function which is 0 and not the calculation.
also the default text shows up while i write the right operator.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string input1,input2,opera,product = "";
        Int32 v,n;

        Console.WriteLine("please insert first number: ");
        input1 = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("please insert second number: ");
        input2 = Console.ReadLine();

        if (numeric(input1, out v) && numeric(input2, out n))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("give operator: *, /, -, +");
            opera = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(operat(product));


        }

     private static string operat(string oper){

        double input1 = 0, input2 = 0;
        double calculation = 0;

        switch (oper)
        {
            case "*":
                calculation += input1 * input2;
                break;
            case "/":
                calculation += input1 / input2;
                break;
            case "+":
                calculation += input1 + input2;
                break; ;
            case "-":
                calculation += input1 - input2;
                return calculation.ToString();
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("you gave the write operator...");
                break;
        }
        return calculation.ToString();
```

just ignore the numeric function...

Comment: When calling `operat` you are using `product` variable which does not appear to be setup.

Comment: Lol! Just think about it.... hint: what does 0 times 0 equal?

Comment: Looks like a good opportunity to practice with a debugger. Step through the code, inspecting the value of each variable at every step. When you get to point where a variable has a value other than the one you expected, figure out why and fix that problem. Rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your operat function to

```
private static string operat(string oper,double input1,double input2)
```

And remove this line

```
double input1 = 0, input2 = 0;
```

And call operat function

```
operat(opera,double.Parse(input1),double.Parse(input2));
```

Comment: You almost have it... Are you sure you are passing the right parameters?

Comment: i figured it out with your help, thanks for taking your time.

Comment: @xwpedram as pointed on the first comment of this question, you should pass opera instead of product.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you name your variables the same in different functions (`input1` and `input2`), it doesn't mean they'll have the same values. In fact they don't even have the same type! Try to remove the `=0` part to see it for yourself, the compiler will tell you it was never assigned to.

What you want is to only have the variables holding the operands and operator in the main function and pass them down to your work functions.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the input1 and input2 in the static void main to class fields. Use these references in the operation method. The input1 and input2 variables in the operator method is not holding the values that are captured in your static void main method. These are just local variables of the method